# In Angular 7 when passing data from one component to another, do I use a service and subscribe/listen in the receiving component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-observable

I'm new to Angular 7 and I'd like to know if I'm on the right path.

I have an 'alert' component that just displays a boostrap alert box on the page at the top.
I want to be able to call this alert and display it from any component.

I'm pretty sure I need a service that I can call to pass a message and then have the alert component subscribe to the service to listen for incoming messages?

So far I can call the service and pass it a 'message' I just don't know how to subscribe/listen (I think that's the right terminology) in the alert component to listen for incoming messages to display.

ex. LoginComponent

```js
constructor(public authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private alert: AlertService) {}

login() {
  this.authService.login(this.model).subscribe(next => {
    this.alert.success('Logged in successfully');
  }, error => {
    this.alert.failure('Log in failed');
  }, () => {
    // do something else
  });
}
```

and then here is my service

ex. AlertService

```js
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AlertService {

  constructor() {}

  success(message: string) {
  // do something here?
  }

  error(message: string) {
  // do something here?
  }
}
```

and then I have my AlertComponent, but not sure how I would subscribe/listen for incoming messages ti display from the AlertService.

ex. AlertComponent.ts

```js
export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {
  dismissible = true;
  alerts: any[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.add();
  }

  // do something here to subscribe/listen to incoming messages from the service??

  add(): void {
    this.alerts.push({
      type: 'info',
      msg: `This alert will be closed in 5 seconds (added: ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()})`,
      timeout: 5000
    });
  }
 
}
```

and the html

```html
<div *ngFor="let alert of alerts">
  <alert [type]="alert.type" [dismissible]="dismissible" [dismissOnTimeout]="alert.timeout">{{ alert.msg }}</alert>
</div>
```

Comment: Go and learn RxJs first. This is a standard solution that would be done with behavior subjects in your service. Stop learning Angular for a day and come back once you know what an observable, subject and behavior subject are. You need to have a good grasp on RxJs before Angular.

Comment: thanks for the advice! Just found a great website.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read [Angular Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection). 
To have injectable service at disposal in some component you must put it constructor and let Angular DI to provide it: Costructor of AlertComponent  shoud have:

```
constructor ( private/proteced alertService:AlertService) { 
   alertService.subsribe ((par)=> {
   this.add(par); 
   ...})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have preaty a lot to learn. This is just lazy made example becouse overwrite observable every time. It's not an perfect code but shows a little bit how Observables work.

Alert Service:

```
    import {
    Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AlertService {

    alerts: Observable<any>

    constructor() { }

    success(message: any) {
        this.alerts = of(message)
    }

    error(message: string) {
        this.alerts = of(message)
    }
}
```

Allert component where alert showns:

```
export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {
    dismissible = true;

    // just inject service
    constructor(public alerts$: AlertService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngIf="alerts$ | async as alerts"> <!-- | async is an pipe it will subscribe for you. importat for observables to first be in *ngIf then in *ngFor loops-->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of alerts">
        <alert[type]="alert.type"[dismissible]="dismissible" [dismissOnTimeout]="alert.timeout"> {{ item }}</alert>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Command triggering alert in any component You want:

```
login() {
    this.authService.login(this.model).subscribe(next => {
      this.alert.success({ type: 'info', timeout: '5000', msg: "Success!"});
    }, error => {
        this.alert.failure({ type: 'info', timeout: '5000', msg: "Success!"}); // `this function u can delete meend failure just succes refactor to 'open'`
    }, () => {
      // do something else
    });
  }
```

About services You need to remember to provide them in `app.module.ts` or any other module like `providers: [AlertService]` So application will know that this is an service. And you inject them eny where You wat by class `constructor()`. When injecting you need allways set an scope for them like 'private public or protected' Or You will end up with regular Variable in type or service class.

About Observables:

There are endless Observables and when you subscribe to them You need to unsubscribe read it abot it some where on internet. `| async` Pipe will do it for You if variable is an endless loop.

Comment: Provide services in the root not modules

Comment: Depend where You want to use them. In laze loding modules You might no need them in whole application.

Comment: The only reason you would provide a service any where other than root is if you need a different instance in different places such as a service that provides data for a component hierarchy. Since Angular 6 there has been no need to provide services in modules at all.

Comment: Oh and good Luck with maintanance root module witch atleast 100 services. May be even dont make any "shared modules" so You will have in one root module 350 components 135 services and 130 extended modules most of them from @angular/material.

Comment: You obviously need to go and read about what provided in root means.